# Continuous and increasing in every variable does not imply continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions, continuity, examples-counterexamples

Let $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$

$z=f(x,y)$

$f$ is continuous and strictly increasing in both $x,y$.

It is known that continuous in each linear directions does not imply continuity.

But the examples that I found all involve non-monotonic functions.

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2},&(x,y)\neq(0,0)\\
0,&(x,y)=(0,0)\\
\end{cases}$$

I wonder if continuous and increasing in every variable implies continuous?

I think the answer is no

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does.

For example, consider function on $[0, 1] \times [0, 1]$ that is continuous increasing in both $x$ and $y$, and $f(0, 0) = 0$. We want to show that $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \delta > 0: x < \delta \wedge y < \delta \rightarrow f(x, y) < \epsilon$.

Because $f$ is continuous in $x$ and $f(0, 0) = 0$, there is $x_0$ s.t. $f(x_0, 0) < \epsilon / 2$. Because $f$ is continuous in $y$, there is $y_0$ s.t. $f(x_0, y_0) < \epsilon$. Now, because $f$ is increasing in $x$ and $y$, if $x < x_0$ and $y < y_0$, then $f(x, y) < \epsilon$. So, taking $\delta = \max(x_0, y_0)$ we get necessary result.